# How to allow user to export Dynamics 365 report to PDF format only?

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

Right now when users choose to export a report from my Dynamics 365 system, they can select the following formats: csv, pdf, mhtml, xlsx, tif, docx.

How can I restrict users to export to pdf format only?

I'm using Dynamics 365 Online Version 1612 (8.2.2.154) (DB 8.2.2.154).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible, atleast in CRM online. But found out the config is stored in `RSReportServer.config`

> The WORDOPENXML extension defines the Word renderer for Microsoft Word .docx files. The WORD extension defines the Microsoft Word 2003 version. Visible = “false” indicates the Word 2003 renderer is hidden.

[Hiding Export option from Report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-word-report-builder-and-ssrs)

> Change how the rendering extension name appears in the Export list of the report toolbar (for example, to change "Web archive" to "MHTML"), or localize the name to a different language.

[Customize Rendering Extension Parameters in RSReportServer.Config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/customize-rendering-extension-parameters-in-rsreportserver-config)